# Rebuilding Multiple Partitions of a Table with Clustered Column Store Index

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, partitioning, columnstore

I created a Table with partitions (on the date column) of a table with a clustered column store index.
I am able to run Index Rebuilds on each partition as needed, which is definitely faster than rebuilding the whole index.
All the partitions are in the default **PRIMARY** file group, and hold a month's data.

#### Issue:

When I run index rebuild on 2 partitions at the same time, it runs the commands in sequence, instead of simultaneously. Even if they are triggered in different sessions, one command will be blocked till the other one is finished. (MAXDOP = 8 , did not change this behaviour)

Do I have to put each partition in a different file? (create a new file group for this table), in order to rebuild these partitions at the same time?

I tried using MAXDOP = 8 (We have 8 CPUs), I tried running the Two index rebuild commands (which were for different partitions of the same table) in 2 different sessions.

I expected both partitions to be rebuilt at the same time as the rebuild command is affecting only a particular section of the table, and would not block other partitions from being rebuilt

Comment: Creating partitions on differents file won't affect the behaviour. There are some differences between the Standard version and the Enterprise about partitions. But I think this behaviour is the fact of statistics.... 
So it depends if you are under Enterprise or not and if you have incremental ststistics or not...

Comment: Does the rebuild of a single partition use more than one CPU?

Comment: Before I hit rebuild ,2 out of 4 Partitions on the column store table are in OPEN state, others are compressed. If I rebuild One Partition - The following is what I see for the CPUs: a) 8 are Assigned Online,b) 8 are Visible online , c) 10 CPUs are Hidden. To find this out I used -->  SELECT cpu_count FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info ;  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.dm_os_schedulers WHERE status = 'VISIBLE ONLINE'  ; SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.dm_os_schedulers WHERE status != 'VISIBLE ONLINE' ;

Comment: This was the case with MAXDOP = 8 ,as well as without using MAXDOP. Any other value like 4 or 7 just takes more time

Comment: Take a look at the locks being requested by the second rebuild process. I suspect that there is a some sort of schema lock (either stability or modification) being held on the table by the first process that is blocking subsequent rebuild operations from even starting.

Comment: I checked this, a rebuild index (on even one partition) will put a Schema Modification Lock (Sch-M) , this is a table level lock. If i run another index rebuild on the 2nd partition , it requests another such lock(Sch-M)  but it is not granted till the first one is completed.

Comment: To try and overcome this, I tried temporarily setting the LOCK-ESCALATION setting for this Partitioned Table to "AUTO" instead of the Default "TABLE" . Auto Mode lets you put a lock on a Partition , instead of directly on the whole table in case of a query affecting a lot of rows in just one partition. This did not work as it still took a Sch-M lock, on the whole table. Looks like You can only rebuild one partition at any given time.